# Nginx Rewrite Issue with question mark urls

Tags: nginx

I have only one issue with Nginx,

I need to rewrite code for:

```
domain.com/?fileID  -> /domain.com/xx.php?i=fileID
```

Note: there is a question mark in the link :)

for more than 10 days I tried many many types of codes to make this work but I could get anything to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
server {
    server_name domain.com;

    location = / {
        if ($args ~* ^[a-z0-9]+$) {
            rewrite ^ /xx.php?i=$args? last;
        }
    }

    location \.php$ {
        # your php handler configuration
    }
}
```

It would be better if you specify how "fileID" looks like and give some examples.

Comment: Great,

i tried it, but the code you just submitted rewrite all my site's URLs that containing "?"

i need it only rewrite the URLs only beginning with "?"

fileID its normal like "sdjkfhs77ds"

Comment: Thank You friend its working fine now :), please check your email